# AT command to register to network

Tags: c#, gsm, modem

I am trying use a ZTE Modem for testing purpose to send and receive sms on c# application.
This is the modem I am using.
http://www.flipkart.com/zte-mf190-3g-data-card/p/itmdhhrb6jwx9gjs.

I am facing a problem when the software that is comes with the device is open, the device is registered to network as soon I close that software, the light on modem become red.

I thinks that the software comes with device sending a command to modem to register to network, but don't know which

I tried with AT+COPS=0

but no luck.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why it is downvoted ?? please tell

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Is there any solution for this? In my case I need to connect to the network using AT commands!

Answer (score 2):

You can try with

```
AT+COPS=1,0,"network long alphanumeric name"
```

this AT command is to try forcing manual connection.

Visit this page for more information http://m2msupport.net/m2msuppor. There you can find also the option to download an AT COMMANDS TESTER, that is really useful.

Answer (score 1):

You must consider that any 3G device like this will have at least 3 states. Unregistered to network, registered to network (SIM active), connected to internet gateway.

Software must move the device between these states through AT commands, or at the very least hardware signals

As a serial connection, only one piece of software can have control - You must accept the AP interfaces provided by the vendors software, or write your own - You can't depend on the manufacturers software to initiate the connection, and hope you can piggyback on it without the device closing connectivity on exit

Answer (score 0):

In my case I tried:

1. send `at+cops?` and your modem should response something like `+COPS: 0,2,51010`
2. send `at+cops=1,2,51010` , where param `1` should attempt to register your modem to network, and the other parameters followed from your modem response, in my case `2, 51010`
3. wait for `OK` signal. If you receive `OK`, then you can try again send `at+cops?` to gain network registration info of your modem.
4. Your modem should response something like `+COPS: 1,2,51010`, which means you are registered to a network.